# How to decide between "ahora" and "ya" for the sense "now"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, adverbios, sinónimos

I know that *`ya`* has additional meanings besides simply *`now`*, such as *`already`*.

But considering just the sense of *`ya`* which does mean *`now`*, when should I use it and when should I use *`ahora`*, which only has the sense *`now`*?

Are there some rules, subtleties, or differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are indeed some differences between the two:

From RAE

> [ahora.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ahora)
>
> (De agora).
>
> 1. adv. t. A esta hora, en este momento, en el tiempo actual o presente.
> 2. adv. t. Poco tiempo ha. Ahora me lo han dicho.
> 3. adv. t. Dentro de poco tiempo. Ahora te lo diré.
> 4. adv. t. Am. hoy.
> 5. conj. distrib. Ahora hable de ciencias, ahora de artes, siempre es atinado su juicio.
> 6. conj. advers. Pero, sin embargo.
>
> [ya.](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ya)
>
> (Del lat. iam).
>
> 1. adv. t. Denota el tiempo pasado. Ya hemos hablado de esto más de una vez.
> 2. adv. t. Inmediatamente, ahora mismo. U. t. en sent. enfático. Aumento de salarios, ya.
> 3. adv. t. En el tiempo presente, haciendo relación al pasado. Era muy rico, pero ya es pobre.
> 4. adv. t. En tiempo u ocasión futura. Ya nos veremos. Ya se hará eso.
> 5. adv. t. Finalmente o últimamente. Ya es preciso tomar una resolución.
> 6. adv. t. Luego, inmediatamente. U. cuando se responde a quien llama. Ya voy. Ya van.
> 7. adv. t. U. como conjunción distributiva. Ya en la milicia, ya en las letras. Ya con gozo, ya con dolor.
> 8. adv. t. U. para conceder o apoyar lo que nos dicen. Ya se ve. Ya entiendo.

Ya, as you said is *now* and *already*

Ahora has some other subtleties, ahora also means *now* and *already*

BUT:

Ya is more immediate, in this precise moment in time. Ahora can mean in the close future, or something that is in the process of being done.

Additionally ahora can be used as a conjunction for example:

> Ahora bien

Translated into

> Nevertheless, Even though, nonetheless...

Now the main difference between the two is that ya is in the **PAST**, and ahora may be in the **PRESENT** or in the **FUTURE**

For example:

> Ahora vamos al cine, espero que vengas.
>
> We are going to the cinema, I hope you come.

As per comments:

**Ahora mismo** means right now, that would be adjusting the meaning for the immediate present, it makes an emphasis with mismo, making it even more immediate than ya. **Ya** and **ahora mismo** mean almost the same thing, but there is a nuance. **Ahora mismo** has a sense and tone of urgency with no need of exclamation marks. But IMHO if ya has the exclamation marks then it would be the equivalent as ahora mismo.

```
Ahora mismo != ya
Ahora mismo == ¡Ya!
```

As for **ahorita** can mean many things and is mostly used in slang. What are these many things well, ahorita is specific of time, you can't say "ahorita que" (okay actually you can but it sounds horribly awkward), usually ahorita can mean in the close future. In 10 or 5 minutes.

> Ahorita voy a lavar mi ropa mamá.
>
> I will go soon to wash my clothes mom.

Comment: Aha the time factor hadn't occurred to me before. But this makes me wonder how "ahora mismo" and (in the case of Mexico) "ahorita" fit in...

Comment: I edited it for you :-)

Comment: This is becoming a really good answer - sorry I can only vote for it once! When I asked about "ahora mismo" and "ahorita" it was because you said "Ya is more immediate" but now you say "Ahora mismo means ... the immediate present". So maybe you can clarify if these two "immediate now" senses are the same or different. I hope this doesn't mess up your format though (-:

Comment: I edited it again :-) I don't do it so much for the vote anyway. I hope it is now clear :D

Comment: @hippietrail The Mexicans like to use “ahorita” for “ahora mismo”.

Comment: As an example of "ahorita" imagine this dialog between a mom and a kid: Mom: Limpia tu cuarto ("Clean up your room"). Kid: Ahorita ("in a minute"). Mom: AHORITA!! ("RIGHT NOW!!"). So "ahorita" can be very confusing for a non-native speaker. You really need to know these subtleties and pay a lot of attention to the context in which it is being said.

Answer (score 10):

Briefly, "ya" means "up to now," (the past and the immediate present), while "ahora" means "now and in the near future."

Answer (score 4):

I would say "ahora" = "now" and "ya" = "right now".

For example, in a colloquial conversation:

> -¿Cuándo debemos salir?
>
> -Ahora.
>
> -¿Ahora cuándo? ¿En cinco minutos?
>
> -¡No, ya!

Answer (score 2):

***Ahora*** is applied to case when something is presently occurring. Possible alternative translation would be *currently*.

***Ya*** is applied to case when something just has occurred. Possible alternative translation would be *already*.

Comment: How might we choose between *actualmente* and *ahora* if I can throw that into the mix? (-:

Comment: For example "Estoy occupado actualmente" would mean "I'm currently busy", while "Estoy occupado ahora" would mean "I'm busy right now". But on the other hand "Ahora vivo en Madrid" would be equivalent to "Actualmente vivo en Madrid" (later sounding more formal).